# High traffic rails perf tuning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I was attempting to evaluate various Rails server solutions.  First on my list was an nginx + passenger system.  I spun up an EC2 instance with 8 gigs of RAM and 2 processors, installed nginx and passenger, and added this to the nginx.conf file:

```
passenger_max_pool_size 30;
passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
rails_framework_spawner_idle_time 0;
rails_app_spawner_idle_time 0;
rails_spawn_method smart;
```

I added a little "awesome" controller to rails that would just `render :text => (2+2).to_s`

Then I spun up a little box and ran this to test it:

```
ab -n 5000 -c 5 'http://server/awesome'
```

And the CPU while this was running on the box looked pretty much like this:

```
05:29:12 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
05:29:36 PM     all     62.39      0.00     10.79      0.04     21.28      5.50
```

And I'm noticing that it takes only 7-10 simultaneous requests to bring the CPU to <1% idle, and of course this begins to seriously drag down response times.

So I'm wondering, is a lot of CPU load just the cost of doing business with Rails?  Can it only serve a half dozen or so super-cheap requests simultaneously, even with a giant pile of RAM and a couple of cores?  Are there any great perf suggestions to get me serving 15-30 simultaneous requests?

Update: tried the same thing on one of the "super mega lots and lots of CPUs" EC2 thing.  Holy crap was that a lot of CPU power.  The sweet spot seemed to be about 2 simultaneous requests per CPU, was able to get it up to about 630 requests/second at 16 simultaneous requests.  Don't know if that's actually cost efficient over a lot of little boxes, though.

Comment: Also, is this a Rails question for Stack Overflow or a performance question for super user?  I'm a little confused on that point.

Comment: Performance tuning could be a gray area between stackoverflow and serverfault i think

Answer (score 1):

I must say that my Rails app got a massive boost to supporting about 80 concurrent users from about 20 initially supported after adding some memcached servers (4 mediums at EC2). I run a high traffic sports site that really hit it a few months ago. Database size is about 6 gigs with heavy updates/inserts.

MySQL (RDS large high usage) cache also helped a bit.

I've tried playing with the passenger settings but got some curious results - like for example each thread eats up 250 megs of RAM which is odd considering the application isn't that big.

You can also save massive $ by using spot instances but don't rely entirely on that - their pricing seems to spike on occasion. I'd AutoScale with two policies - one with spot instances and another with on demand (read: reserved) instances.

Comment: My I ask about how much are your monthly RDS costs?

Comment: about $160 or $250 or something like that, the up-front cost was about $2000 as I can remember.

Comment: Thanks! We just use MySQL with a high-iops ec2 and do our own daily backups, but we're considering it.